# PHP value null into sql server insert statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I would like to insert value `NULL` in to sql server table.

```
$value = $_POST['value'];

then PDO with (INSERT .... :value.....)
```

and `execute(array(':value' => "$value"));`
but when html input field is empty I got empty field on sql but I would like to see `NULL`
I tried with

```
if ($_POST['value'] ==''){$value = NULL;}else{....}
```

but nothing happens.

My sql table looks like:

```
[field] [varchar](20)  NULL,
```

Comment: You shouldn't need quotes around `$value` in the `execute` statement. Can you remove those and try again?

Comment: field must accept null value and it must be without default value... then insert a new record without give the field any value .. it will take null automatically

Comment: hot to change that on management studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `NULL` values in prepared statements in general: ANY `NULL` value that *was* actually bound into statement, is **always** being sent to database as `NULL`. No exceptions.

Example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT isnull(?)");
$stmt->execute(array(NULL));
var_dump($stmt->fetchColumn());
// string(1) "1"
```

Regarding your particular code, as it was pointed out in the comments, your problem is caused by wrong syntax. In PHP, variables have to be addressed **without quotes.** Quotes are used in PHP to delimit strings. While variables, again, have to be addressed without quotes.

Comment: Except he's cast it to a string : `':value' => "$value"`